# Caculate latest value for Grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have the following Loki query that shows me the error rate for my containers:

```
(sum(rate({namespace="namespace", cluster="cluster", level="error"}[1m])) by (cluster, container, level, namespace))>0.5
```

I use it to create a dashboard in Grafana using the "Stat" type. The only custom fields I used for this dashboard are:

- Calculation: Last non-null value
- Fields: Numeric Fields
- Decimals: 0

The dashboard is configured to show the last 6 hours. My problem is that that when the error rate is zero, the dashboard shows the last value for those 6 hours:

[image: 1]

As you can see in the screenshot, there was a spike in errors, but now there are none, yet the last value shown is still 672.

I'm not sure which calculation to use to resolve this. I tried a few but none of them fit my needs.

I'm open to changing the query if needed, or if there's another workaround that would be great.

Comment: You don't need a calculation. Switch your query type to _Instant_, and you'll get what you need.

Comment: thanks @markalex - with the type Instant, the dashboard only shows 1 container, instead of all of the containers the fall under my query. Not sure why

Comment: Don't use calculation: use *All values* instead.

Comment: Thank you @markalex - I have one more question regarding this. I used `{{container}}` in the legend to only show the container name, but now it shows the namespace, cluster, error level and container name combined. It ignores my specification in the legend. Perhaps I need to use something else?

Comment: Not, AFAIK, this is a bug in Grafana's integration with Loki data source. Consider looking through Grafana's issues in their repo, and if something like this is not already filed - filing it.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my issue. Feel free to reply and I'll mark it as the answer.